# Can't enable "Show CPU usage" on emulator

Tags: android

When I click on "Show CPU usage" checkbox, nothing happens. Checkbox does not get checked.

```
Dev Tools > Development Settings > Show CPU usage
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Also having this problem, anyone found a solution?

Comment: Which SDK version are you using? Which operating systems? That will help.

Comment: I can confirm that it does work on API3 and API4, but not on API7 or higher. Tested it on a Windows 7 machine (64 bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use `adb shell` and then type in `top`. There should be all the info you need.

On some machines it will not work, because the TERM Variable is not set.
You can set it by typing:

`export TERM=xterm`

Answer (score 0):

That works for me too. Is there anyway to get top to refresh in the same view within the terminal instead of having to manually scroll down?